# Book about a vampire like creature

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

In the book a man becomes described with vampiric qualities that he acquired after disturbing a burial ground who then must defeat someone like him but stronger and there is a city in the sky. The word vampire is never actually mentioned. I don’t even remember the author name but it’s not one that is well known I wish I could remember more thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this a contemporary setup? Medieval? Fantasy setting with magic commonplace?

Comment: Please visit [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for prompts on what you might be able to [edit] into your question. Visiting the [tour] will tell you a bit more about the site, and how to accept an answer once posted.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?  Is the burial ground a cemetery, a barrow...?

Comment: What sort of vampiric qualities does he have? Supernatural strength? Unable to die except via beheading? Rapid counting ability? Flight? Being able to turn into a cloud of bats? Can control wolves? Impeccable fashion sense and popped collars?

Comment: Warrior and a "city in the sky" are mentioned in "Angelos Odyssey" by J. B. M. Patrick: https://ru.scribd.com/book/399434586/Angelos-Odyssey-Volume-One

Comment: Possibly one of Brian Lumley's *Necroscope* novels?